# Triangle Recursion Java

Tags: java, recursion, geometry

takes two numbers m and n on the command line and writes out a triangle pattern of asterisks

```
public class Triangle {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    if(args.length!=0){
        a=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        b=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    }
    printFirstHalf(a,b);
    printSecondHalf(a,b);
}

public static void printFirstHalf(int m, int n){

    if(m==0){
        return;
    }

    //recursive step
    for(int i=m; i<=n; i++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
    printFirstHalf(m-1,n);


}

public static void printSecondHalf(int m, int n){
    if(m==0){
        return;
    }
    printSecondHalf(m-1,n);

    //recursive step
    for(int i=m; i<=n; i++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();


}
}
```

If 3 and 7 are sent in it should print:

```
***
****
*****
******
*******
*******
******
*****
****
***
```

Right now it prints out:

```
*****
******
*******
*******
******
*****
```

I know I am close but for some reason I am majorly stuck.

Comment: Looks like it's time to debug the problem.

Comment: This is what debuggers are for.

Comment: Please provide some further details about what you tried to do to solve the problem and then narrow down your question based on your attempts. As it is this question is too broad for SO and you will not get helpful answers. Have you tried using the debugger to see what happens to your variables while the program is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this:

```
public static void printFirstHalf(int m, int n){
    if(m>n){
        return;
    }

    // print asterix
    for(int i=1; i<=m; i++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();

    // recurse
    printFirstHalf(m+1,n);
}
```

Do you see where you went wrong with your other method now?

If you're working with recursion for the first time, I understand that it can be difficult but there is no 'magic' with recursion. Work through the code step-by-step and understand what it does. In this case you weren't actually printing the number of asterix needed. Keep at it.

Answer (score 0):

Your first half could be like this (incremental logic> :

```
public static void printFirstHalf(int m, int n){

    if(m>n){
        return;
    }

    //recursive step
    for(int i=1; i<=m; i++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
    printFirstHalf(m+1,n);

}
```

Would suggest you to write similar decremental logic for second half