# Mirrored Triangle generation in java

Tags: java, loops

I happened to appear for a test and got the following as question. I am unable to figure out how to proceed. The scenario is to write a java program that prints the following with respective N. If suppose N=3, it must have 2*N rows and output must be,

1 
2*3
4*5*6
4*5*6
2*3
1

Output must consist only numbers and asterisk. N varies between 0 to 100. Also, given

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int rows=2;
    mirrorTriangle(rows);
}
public void mirrorTriangle(int n){
    //Logic 
}
```

I don't understand why is that rows declared as 2 if rows are supposed to be varying with N. Please explain the logic.

Comment: homework ?? any issue with code that u write ?

Comment: Came across this in a interview process. I dont know to proceed.

Comment: If `given` means that you can write your code only where `//Logic` is, than you misunderstood/misremembered something. That makes no sense (and the problem is impossible). Exact problem formulation could be helpful. If that is just an example of code structure - yes, the answer is going to look something like that, nothing more to explain.

Comment: I think you neet to look into recursion and maintaining a recursive index. Then things might clear up for you.

Comment: This was what given and asked :(

Comment: Even if i use recursion, i confuse with displaying a asterisk in between numbers. I am completely new to this type of outputs.

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742894/triangle-recursion-java - and there are lots of other answers, on the same topic. Search a little.
And please attempt something before asking for our help.

Comment: Is there a specific requirement to use recursion? The structure of the sample implies it, but it is not specified.

Comment: No, They didnt specify any @robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the solution to your problem, with explanation comments.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // initialize n
        int n = 4;
        // initialize x to 1 from where our printing will start.
        int x = 1;
        /* We will store our generated numbers in an array.
         * For example, the array after we generate 
         * the numbers would look like:
         * [1,0,0,
            2,3,0,
            4,5,6,
            4,5,6,
            2,3,0,
            1,0,0]
         * 
         * When n = 3, there are going to be 3*2 i.e, n*2 rows.
         * in our case 6 rows. 
         * visualize with the above values.
         * The first n/2 rows will be the numbers we print, 
         * the next n/2 will be the mirror image of the first n/2 rows.
         * no. of columns in each row will be equal to n, in our example:3
         */
        int arr[][] = new int[n*2][n];
        /*
         * Start populating the matrix
         * Each row will contain number of elements eaual to the row number,
         *  so 1st row -> 1 element, 2nd - > 2,.. and so on.
         */
        for(int row=0;row<n;row++)
        {
            int col = 0;
            while(col < row+1)
            {
                arr[row][col] = arr[n*2-row-1][col] = x++;
                col++;
            }
        }
        /*
         * Now our task is just to read out the array.
         * The tricky part is adding the astricks.
         * We notice that row1 will have 1-1 asticks, row2 -> 2-1 astricks ,.. and so on.
         * So in between the numbers while reading out,
         * for each row we maintain the number of astricks.
         */
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
            for(int j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++)
            {
                if(arr[i][j] > 0)
                {
                    build.append((arr[i][j])).append("*");
                }
            }
            System.out.print(build.delete(build.length()-1,build.length()).toString());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

o:p for n=4:

```
1
2*3
4*5*6
7*8*9*10
7*8*9*10
4*5*6
2*3
1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def N = 3
def i = 0
def j = 0
int[][] numbers = new int[N][]

// Generate, print, and store numbers
while( i < numbers.length ){
    numbers[i] = new int[i+1]
    j = 0
    while( j < numbers[i].length ){
        numbers[i][j] = j+1
        ++j
        print j
    }
    println ""
    i++
}

// Print them again, in reverse order
i = numbers.length - 1
while( i >= 0 ){
    j = 0
    while( j < numbers[i].length ){
        print numbers[i][j]
        j++
    }
    println ""
    i--
}
```

Output:

```
1
12
123
123
12
1
```

The code is pretty self-explanatory. You need just `N` rows but print `2N` because, wait for it ... symmetry. If you have 6 rows, first 3 are new while the other 3 are just mirrored images so why waste the memory space when you can just print them again?

Comment: @BatScream *Screams* dafuq ? LOL The idea was to let the OP figure it out. I am glad you cannot down vote twice. See the sequence of numbers I use. It is different from what OP wants ;)

Comment: Wish i had an option to down vote again, no explanation comments in your code, the OP had asked for. Anyway, your memory optimization is good.

Comment: @BatScream The OP went for a job interview when he got this question. I guess I have said more than enough in code :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there an explicit requirement for recursion? It is implied by the structure of the problem not mentioned anywhere.

`int rows=2` is an example probably, for the purposes of the problem you can't do anything 'smart' like using pointers ...

I will also assume that you are not permitted to use values '> 100' so that you can overload the meaning of the `n` value - same goes for 2's complement.

If you allow for looping, as a substitute for recursion you can generate the triangle without having to save state outside of the stack:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int rows=3;
    mirrorTriangle(rows);
}

public static void mirrorTriangle(int n){

    for (int i = 0 ; i < n + 1 ; i++) {

        renderLine(i);
    }

    for (int i = n ; i > 0 ; i--) {

        renderLine(i);
    }
}

private static void renderLine(int n) {

    int j = n * (n - 1) / 2 + 1;
    int k = j + n;

    while (j < k) {

        System.out.print(j);
        j++;
        if (j < k) System.out.print('*');
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fresh code:

```
public class String4 {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int rows = 3;    
        mirrorTriangle(rows);    
    }    
    private static void mirrorTriangle(int rows) {    
        for(int i=1;i<=rows;i++)    
        {    
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)    
            {    
                System.out.print(i);    
                if(j>0&&j<i)    
                System.out.print("*");    
            }    
            System.out.println();    
        }    
        for(int k=rows;k>0;k--)    
        {    
            for(int l=1;l<=k;l++)    
            {    
                System.out.print(k);    
                if(l>0&&l<k)    
                    System.out.print("*");    
            }    
            System.out.println();    
        }    
    }    
}
```

Output:

```
1    
2*2    
3*3*3    
3*3*3    
2*2    
1
```

Comment: Code is indented by 4 spaces on StackOverflow. You can select the code and press Ctrl+K to indent all of it at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better and simple solution than the chosen one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter limit");
    int limit = s.nextInt();
    int start[] = new int[limit];
    int v = 1;
    for (int i=1; i<=limit; i++) {
        start[i-1] = v;
            for (int j=1; j<=i; j++) {
                System.out.print(v++);
                if(j==i)
                    continue;
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
    }
    for (int i=limit-1; i>=0; i--) {
        v=start[i];
            for (int j=i; j>=0; j--) {
                System.out.print(v++);
                if(j==0)
                    continue;
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.print("\n"); 
    }
}
```